# jquery only allow one button to be checked

Tags: jquery, button

ive got 5 buttons that user can check. for a moment the code allowing user to check more than 1 button. **i want, soon they click second button, the alert dialog appear, whether they want to want to carry the process or not, if yes it will add `checked class` to the selected button**.

```
<form class="table_book">
<input id="block_book" type="button" value="first" class="checked">
<input id="block_book" type="button" value="second">
<input id="block_book" type="button" value="third">
<input id="block_book" type="button" value="fourth">
<input id="block_book" type="button" value="fifth">
</form>

$("input#block_book").live('click',function(){
  if($(".table_book #block_book").hasClass("checked").length > 1) {
     if(var conf = confirm('Are you sure want to select the button?'))
        // ajax process
     } else {
       // remove unchecked class 
     }
  }
})
```

Comment: IDs must be identical. Use `class` instead if you want them to share a type like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first job is to convert the inputs to use a common class rather than an ID

**HTML**

```
<form class="table_book">
    <input class="block_book" type="button" value="first">
    <input class="block_book" type="button" value="second">
    <input class="block_book" type="button" value="third">
    <input class="block_book" type="button" value="fourth">
    <input class="block_book" type="button" value="fifth">
</form>
```

If I've understood your requirements properly, then this code should work. The first button can be selected freely. Clicking a second button will raise a prompt to confirm the change.

**jQ**

```
$(function() {
    $("input.block_book").live('click', function() {
        var setClass = true;
        if ($("input.block_book.checked").length > 0)
            setClass = confirm('Are you sure want to select the button?');

        if (setClass) {
            // ajax process 
            $("input.block_book").removeClass("checked")
            $(this).addClass("checked")
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't totally understand the logic you are trying to apply here (e.g. does their answer to the "are you sure" question determine whether or not more than one box can be checked?

Also, I am not sure what you're trying to determine with the "if" -- `hasClass` returns `true` or `false`, it's not a selector.

But to answer the actual title of your question, how to check only one, just do this in a click event. Apply the logic you want as appropriate.

```
 $(".table_book #block_book.checked").removeClass("checked");
 $(this).addClass("checked");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t3FNy/1/

As another answer noted- IDs should be unique. While this will work it is not good practice, and there's no added value to having an ID at all in this code.

Answer (score 0):

there is actually a fatal error in your source code. All buttons have got the same id's. Please change that.

After that modify also the first line to `$("form .table_book").find(":input[type='button']").live('click',function() {`

Comment: For an improvement: Store the result of '$("form .table_book")' in an extra variable so you can use it serveral times. Even for counting the number of classes "checked".